# how to change independent variable set to 0?

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm working on a multiple linear regression with 8 independent variables and a dependent variables, all of them measured at the continuous level.
One of these independent variables value is zero for the 80% of the observations, then it turns to a value close to the range of the other independent variables.
That independent variable is zero, in the first observations, because it didn't exist until a certain point: after that, it's present in every observation. 
In my prediction model this variable does exist, but due to the huge amount of observations in the training set where its value is zero, it seems not to be influent for the prediction. 
What should I do to change the first 80% of data in order to obtain more reliable predictions? Should I change the value of this independet variable from zero to...?

Comment: Since multiple regression doesn't require data normalization, please explain what you hope to achieve by normalization.

Comment: @whuber sorry... I used the world ‘normalize’ in the wrong way... I just would like to neutralize the 0 effects...

Comment: Could you please explain what "neutralize the 0 offsets" means?

Comment: I mean this: the independent variable with a lot of 'zero values' observations, starts having significant values at a certain moment in time... but due to the past observations, regression doesn't give too much importance to it in the prediction... but this variable is very important for my dataset, because, even if it didn't exist in the previous observations, it does exist later and will exist in the future with values far from zero.